# How to Add Script to Success Page of OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart-3

I develop payment gateway extension at opencart 3. I need to add some js script to success page without change core opencart files. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom script on your success page by adding such like code 
in your **catalog/controller/checkout/success.php index method**

Example

```
public function index() {
    $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/my_javascript.js');
    $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/css/my_custom.css');
   }

//$this->document->addScript($URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT)
//$this->document->addStyle($URL_TO_YOUR_STYLE)
```

Remember to refresh your modifications